# Using Libcurl properly in Qt application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, libcurl

I am new to both Qt and libcurl. I now need to use libcurl in my Qt application.  I started with:

```
m_res = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
```

Then I emit a signal which gives this string to another application

```
emit dataString (QString::fromStdString(dataBufferfromcurl));
```

I have connected this signal to an slot in other application. But when the curl is called, it's blocking the other program by reading data. Can someone suggest me how to use licurl properly in a Qt application?

Here's some more-complete code:

```
Class A : public QObject{
void init(){
 if (m_curl){
   curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com"); 
   curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L); // enabling ssl 
   curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
   curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
   curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
   curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);//

}
void process(){
  if (m_curl) {     
    m_res = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
  }
};

//*************************************************************

class B : QThread{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  void runProcess(){
    aObject = new A(); 
    ///************ few more connects
    connect(aObject, SIGNAL(connectionError(QString)), this, SLOT(s_fireConnectionError(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, workingHTTPReader, SLOT(process()));
  }    
} ;
```

In  class C, I call `B::runProcess()`:

```
void C:: getAllData()
{
    bObject = new B;
    bObject->runProcess(); //***********Problem     
}
```

If I call it this way, it reads the web page content, but execution of the rest of the application blocks.

How can I call this without blocking?

Comment: Google: `Qt::QueuedConnection`. Or use multi-threading. It's unclear, what problems do you have. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @DmitrySazonov Thanks for replying. And i have  tired both 'Qt::Directconnection' and 'Qt::Queued connection'. .I have explained my problem a little bit clearly. Please have a look on it.

Comment: Use any of QThread / QThreadPool / QtConcurrent for async operations.

Comment: Could you please provide me some example like that. So that I can understand better.  thanks in advance

Comment: No, because stackoverflow is not a free coding service. You need to do a research by yourself. And because there are a lot of examples in internet.

Answer (score 0):

aObject 's thread()  is thread b, and thread b not have evnet loop..
you must start event loop in the thread.
If a QObject has no thread affinity (that is, if thread() returns zero), or if it lives in a thread that has no running event loop, then it cannot receive queued signals or posted events.

Answer (score 0):

You call `B::runProcess()` in the same thread as the rest of the application.  Creating a class that inherits from `QThread` does not automatically make all its methods run in a different thread.

For your purposes, the easiest way to achieve what you're after is to create a thread pool (or, more simply, use the application's default thread pool), and queue your method to execute there:

```
void C:: getAllData()
{
    auto b = new B;
    b->setAutoDelete(true); // if you're not deleting it yourself later
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(hello);   
}
```

Class `B` must inherit from `QRunnable` instead of `QThread`:

```
class B : public QRunnable
{
public:
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
}
```

This is just an outline solution; you'll want to read the Qt documentation of `QRunnable` and `QThreadPool` to get a full understanding of what you're doing.